# Complications and risks for combining multiple procedures

Tags: risks, complications

How do the risks and potential complications change when multiple procedures are performed at the same time? For example both [wisdom tooth extraction](https://www.mayoclinic.org/tests-procedures/wisdom-tooth-extraction/about/pac-20395268) and [LASIK eye surgery](https://www.mayoclinic.org/tests-procedures/lasik-eye-surgery/about/pac-20384774) have relatively minor risks associated with them. There are some factors that increase the risks associated with LASIK surgery, but nothing that seems directly related to wisdom tooth extraction.

There are clinics that do both procedures (different surgeons). Is there a reason to advise a patient against having both procedures done on the same day? Are there benefits of having both procedures done on the same visit?

Comment: Depends on the specific procedures. Some can be combined, some absolutely cannot. You'll need to narrow this down.

Comment: @CareyGregory I think the given example about LASIK surgery and Wisdom teeth removal is precise enough...

Comment: @Narusan If the question is only about that combination then I agree, but the title suggests a more general question that can't be answered. OP needs to clarify if they're asking a general or specific question.

Comment: @CareyGregory presumably there are some general rules which tell us about which procedures can be combined and which absolutely cannot be combined. Further, things like how the risk for infection changes with multiple independent incision sites seems like an answerable question. My concern was that asking only about LASIK and wisdom teeth extraction would be too specific. I guess